# Centering text in TikZ tree node

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

I'd like to have my text inside TikZ tree nodes centered; below is my progress so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=1pt, text centered,
  font=\sffamily},
  arn_m/.style = {treenode, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, text centered, white,
  font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black, text width=7em},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, rectangle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, 
  draw=black, fill=black, text width=2em},
  arn_r/.style = {treenode, rectangle, red, draw=red, 
  text width=3em, very thick},
  arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
  minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}
}

\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1cm}] 
\node [arn_m] {2 3 6 5 7}
    child{ node [arn_r] {15 2} 
            child{ node [arn_n] {10} 
                child{ node [arn_r] {5} edge from parent node[above left]
                         {$x$}} %for a named pointer
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {20}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }                            
    }
    child{ node [arn_r] {47}
            child{ node [arn_n] {38} 
                            child{ node [arn_r] {36}}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {39}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {51}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {49}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
        }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the text in the nodes is not centered properly as it is biased to the right and normal fixing techniques (like putting text centered and so on) do not resolve the problem. Could someone provide me a tip on how to align the node text properly?

Comment: Can you turn this code into a compilable document? Posting fragments isn't terribly helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The culprit seems to be `text width`. If you change it to `minimum width`, then the texts will be centered properly.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  treenode/.style = {align=center, inner sep=1pt,
  font=\sffamily},
  arn_m/.style = {treenode, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, white,
  font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, fill=black, minimum width=7em},
  arn_n/.style = {treenode, rectangle, white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, 
  draw=black, fill=black, minimum width=2em},
  arn_r/.style = {treenode, rectangle, red, draw=red, 
  minimum width=3em, very thick},
  arn_x/.style = {treenode, rectangle, draw=black,
  minimum width=0.5em, minimum height=0.5em}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',level/.style={sibling distance = 5cm/#1,
  level distance = 1cm}] 
\node [arn_m] {2 3 6 5 7}
    child{ node [arn_r] {15 2} 
            child{ node [arn_n] {10} 
                child{ node [arn_r] {5} edge from parent node[above left]
                         {$x$}} %for a named pointer
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {20}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {18}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }                            
    }
    child{ node [arn_r] {47}
            child{ node [arn_n] {38} 
                            child{ node [arn_r] {36}}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {39}}
            }
            child{ node [arn_n] {51}
                            child{ node [arn_r] {49}}
                            child{ node [arn_x] {}}
            }
        }
; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

---

## Comments

- `text centered` may be a deprecated option; I couldn't find it anywhere in the TikZ documentation
- As Alan Munn says in his comment, please help us help you by posting a compilable MWE in the future.

Comment: That seems to be the trick! I was not able to post it immediately but the fragment only was missing a document class and the tikz packages used! I'll refrain from posting non-compilable documents in the future. As always @Kevin thanks for the concise reply.

Comment: @jtimz: Glad it helped `:)` It's still a bit mysterious to me why `text width` should cause the problem, though. But well, if `minimum width` works, then there you go `:)`

Comment: Also @Kevin I wish I could up-vote your answer but the rep system is a bitch at start! Don't you think that I didn't want to!

Comment: @KevinC, `text width` alone sets `align=left` and you need to include `align=center` (or `\centering`) to center node text. It's better explained in pgfmanual 2.10, page 180.

Comment: @Ignasi: `align=center` is set in the definition of `treenode`, but using `text width` still has the problem of node contents not properly centered. I did read those pages you referred to before answering this question. But it doesn't explain the odd behavior observed in this case.

Comment: @KevinC, you are right. `text width` and `minimum width` produce different alignment results with pgf 2.10. May be it's a bug. With cvs version, text is centred with both options.